# Problem with CSS image brackground in diferent browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I'm making a pizza customize frontend and the ideia is we can select half pizza of one type, and the another half of another type.

Now, i'm having problems with background-image in firefox vs chrome vs edge.

CSS:

```
.img-top{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:5;
  width:19%;
  padding:0.4rem;
  opacity:0.5;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.img-responsive{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.hidden {
  visibility:hidden;
}

.sliced-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16.5%;
  margin-top:1.5rem;

  transition: ease 250ms;
}

.sliced-img-small{
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%!important;
  margin-top:5.5rem;
  transition: ease 250ms;
}

.slice {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.esquerdo {
  left: 0;
  background-image: url('imagens/Layer -3.png'); 
  background-position: 0%;
  opacity:0.2;
}

.direito {
  left: 50%;
  background-image: url('imagens/Layer -3.png'); 
  background-position: -100%;
  opacity:0.2;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div id="mudar" class="sliced-img-small ">
                    <img src='imagens/Layer 3.png' class='img-responsive hidden'>
                    <!--esta imagem é só para obter o tamanho correcto dinamicamente -->
                    <div class="slice esquerdo activo "></div>
                    <div class="slice direito activo"> </div>
                </div>
                <img src='imagens/marca_pizza.png' class='img-top'>
 </div>
```

for example:

[image: Firefox]

and:

[image: chrome]

PS: i need to have the image divided in 2 so i can select the half in javascript :p

Comment: Would you be able to add a jsfiddle or codepen?
It would help us to see the issue more clearly.

Comment: Hey, thanks in front, where https://codepen.io/rafaeltpires/pen/abOWbLa but in codepen works like a charm

Comment: Yes, Its working in codepen. Then there might be an issue with your browser or your implementation.

Comment: ok, i tried to put in a new document and get it working in chrome O.o

Thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the link...

"imagens/Layer 3.png"

i changed it and its working fine